# I'm trying to pass a parameter using this

Tags: vb6

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Main(): If Con.Initialize = conLaunchExplorer Then Con.Visible = False
    Dim strParameters As String
    Dim readL As String
     strParameters = Split(Command$, "/")
     Con.WriteLine strParamers
     readL = Con.ReadLine
End Sub
```

This is code right now as you can see I'm trying to split the strParameters  but the error says mismatch please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When **Splitting** a string, the data is placed in an array, and according to your declaration `strParameters` is a simple string. How would the different parts fit in one string? You just need to change your declaration as follows;

```
Dim strParameters() As String
```

Assuming that your Command$ is correctly declared as string, with delimiters `"/"`